# WPF: How do i show a itemsControl inside listbox items with dataset foreign key

Tags: wpf, listbox, foreign-keys, strongly-typed-dataset

I have tried to do as follows but i get  empty items in the itemscontrol. The relation work because i get the itemscontrol filled with the correct number of items, but only with empty items. I have tried everything but can't figure it out. Can someone please help me.

```
<Grid DataContext="{DynamicResource DSDKo}">
    <ListBox   ItemsSource="{Binding tblOrderMachineConversionCheck}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel >
                    <Label Content="{Binding Header}" Width="100" Height="30" Background="Silver"/>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding  Path='FK_tblOrderMachineConversionSubCheck_tblOrderMachineConversionCheck'}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column ="0" Content="{Binding Path=Text}" Height="30" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Width="40" Height="40" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please show us your `FK_tblOrderMachineConversionSubCheck_tblOrderMachineConversionCheck` property and the class definition of whatever type it is.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would you have a ListBox with a DataTemplate holding an ItemsControl.

I would say use TreeView for such situation since your tblOrderMachineConversionCheck seems to have a tree alike data structure.

However your Binding to that inner ItemsControl looks a bit weird to me.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding  Path='FK_tblOrderMachineConversionSubCheck_tblOrderMachineConversionCheck'}">
```

Path='..', what are ' good for? :)

Try to leave those ASCII signs away.

Futhermore if you still cannot display anything but you are sure your FK_tblOrderMachineConversionSubCheck_tblOrderMachineConversionCheck property holds items, then show us your Window Output. There must be some kind of Binding error displayed.